# Added trash can to panel but it opens Gimp

Tags: panel, ubuntu-mate, trash

I added Trash to my panel using Add To Panel.

When I open it, it opens Gimp saying, Gimp Message Opening 'trash:' failed. Can not recursively copy directory.

What is causing that and can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I looked in Preferred Applications and found that the File Manager was set to Gimp.

When I changed it to Thunar, my Trash started working properly.